# Select Query not working as it should -SQL

Tags: sql

I'm building a social network and wanted to show the posts that the user did and the posts from who is he following.

The query works fine when I follow someone, it shows the user posts and the posts of the person who is he following, but when I don't follow anyone, the user posts disappears as well, when it is not supposed too do that:

Table:

[image]

Query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT posts.id, posts.body, posts.posted_at, posts.postimg, posts.likes, users.username
FROM users, posts, followers
WHERE (posts.user_id = followers.user_id OR posts.user_id = 50)
AND users.id = posts.user_id AND follower_id = 50
ORDER BY posts.posted_at DESC;
```

Comment: First rewrite the query using explicit `JOIN` syntax. And then, I guess, some or all of the inner joins should be outer joins instead.

Answer (score 1):

I think, this should give you what you want:

```
SELECT DISTINCT posts.id, posts.body, posts.posted_at, posts.postimg, posts.likes, users.username
FROM posts
LEFT JOIN users ON posts.user_id = users.id
LEFT JOIN followers ON posts.user_id = followers.user_id
WHERE posts.user_id = 50
ORDER BY posts.posted_at DESC;
```

Comment: It worked! but now it is only showing the user posts and if I follow other user I cant see his posts

Answer (score 0):

It is a bit unclear what table your follower_id column is in... So I am assuming your follower_id column is in posts table. If it is, you are filtering down to posts where follower_id = 50, if you are not following anyone, that value should be null, so you are filtering posts out with this filter in your where clause.

Comment: Sorry, forgot to translate to english... I edited the query again, the follower_id is a column of the table followers